# Java application errors (non static variable / symbol errors )

Tags: variables, methods, static, double

i'm writing a application

My brain is hitting a wall, and i have no idea what the problem is.
I've tried googling the problem, but after countless pages it doesn't help. Then , I Re-read the entire chapter of the book i'm currently reading. I can't find the problem. Please show me the problem by writing it out, and explain why it's correct. it's supposed to take the value of bank1 + depositAmount = a number and then display it.

Where to begin?

code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQXDk.jpg

Lines 79, 64
error code: non static variable cannot be referenced from a static context

Line 76, 70
error code= missing cannot find symbol method depositAmount2(double)location variable bank1 of type Banker.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not as bad as it seems.

On line 64 you are having confusion because You have a Banker class that contains two accounts. bank1 and bank2.

On line 62 you create a new object of your Banker class called bank1.
To avoid confusion i suggest you name it bank. (without the 1).

Line 64
You are trying to retrieve data from an object that does not exists.
You can fix that by bank1.getbank2()
Same thing for line 79.

Line 70 is calling a method that does not exists.
Change it to `bank1.deposit(depositAmount)`
Notice that on line 70 you named your method `deposit`

Line 76 is the same as 70 you are calling a method that does not exists.

If it still doesn't make sense let me know and I will explain in detail with code if need be.

Answer (score 0):

The error message has the hint. Your main function is a static function. The first thing you did is that you created bank1 object. But later you started using bank2 object without initializing. Why don't you start off like this so that the code looks less confusing?:

```
Banker banker1= new Banker(50.0, 50.0);
```

Later, you can call `banker1.getBank1()` and `banker1.getBank2()` (note: you are calling `bank2.getBank2()` should be `bank1.getBank2()` )

Also depositAmount functions don't exist. Either use deposit1 and deposit2 as you have implemented or change the name.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever I can decipher from your code image there are two mistakes in it.

You didn't initialise banker2 and trying to initialise.

Declare bank2 similar to how you declared bank1

```
Banker bank2=new Banker(0.00,50.00);
```

The above will solve issues in lines 64,79.

There is no method called depositAmount in Banker class.

You have to use method deposit() instead. This will solve other issues.

Regarding your final output of sum you need to modify your class a lot to achieve that result.